# Как вывести 2 квадрата в цикле for

Tags: java

Как вывести 2 квадрата в цикле for.Решал задачи с вложенными циклами for и необходимо было выводить изображения такого рода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю что решение простое но сколько задач такого типа не решал это сделать не могу

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    if (j<4||i<4) {
                        System.out.print("0 ");
                    } else if(i>1||j>1) {
                        System.out.print("0 ");
                    }else{
                        System.out.print("* ");
}
                }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы управлять индексами, можно считывать значение перед записью. Это поможет обойтись без третьего цикла, в котором значения обоих циклов совпадают.

Answer (score 0):

Вот смотрите - вам всегда нужно выводить n звездочек, но начиная с n-го цикла, перед ними ещё n/2 пробелов

```
int n = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < n * 3 / 2; i++) {

      if (i >= n) 
           for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j++) 
                    System.out.print("  ");

      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
                   System.out.print("* ");

      System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо у меня была похожая задумка насчет если i <4 то J<4 и все это в 1 if написать, но не догадался использовать в нем еще 1 цикл, благодарю за помощь.